# IOS unpredictable array sorting while enumerating

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform

I'm loading a collection view with a query from parse.com that is sorted by newest objects first. My problem is that I'm seeing unpredictable ordering. On initial launch it always has the correct ordering but after refreshing the ordering will always change.

My query returns me an NSArray called objects and I iterate through this array and add the listingPhotos key to an array _images.

```
for (id object in objects) {
  [_images addObject:[object objectForKey:@"listingPhotos"]];
}
```

_images now contains an array of arrays:

```
(
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f1703d70>",
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f14c9320>"
 ),
    (
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f1708810>",
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f14da500>"
 ),
    (
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f1486920>",
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f14bdfe0>"
 ),
    (
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f14f0620>",
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f15fa0e0>",
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f15a6830>"
 ),
    (
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f164d7e0>"
 ),
    (
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f160cc70>",
    "<PFFile: 0x7f96f1669210>"
 )
)
```

I only want to grab the first image from each array so I iterate through like so. _thumbnail is a PFFile. I then download each file and add the images to _imagesArray which is then used later to fill the cells:

```
for(id object in _images) {
  _thumbNail = [object firstObject];
[_thumbNail2 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    [_imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
{
```

When I log this second loop it always grabs the first image so I know the problem is in the first loop.

I also have a pull down refresh action but all it does is load the query:

```
- (void)refresh:(id)sender {
  [self parseQuery];
  [(UIRefreshControl *)sender endRefreshing];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was cause by a clumsy error of initializing the arrays within the query.